# Create button on top of 2 div containers

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a page-piling webpage where this section's background color is a gradient set through CSS. 
I have created a gray coloured div for the bottom of this section, but what I'm struggling with is to place the 3 buttons to overlap over the gray and orange. How is that part done?

Also is it possible to make the gray bar on the bottom without it being the footer of the page? I only want it to be visible for this section, but not for the others.

The preview of what I would like it to look like is here:
[image]

Comment: And, You post none code.

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: Welcome to [stackoverflow] (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) please share what you have tried. then if you got stucked with some exact issue, we will help you. Refer these links for asking proper questions (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , (http://stackoverflow.com//help/mcve) and (http://sscce.org)

Comment: you dont need to create 2 divs to apply multiple colors. let me give you an example

Answer (score 4):

Using one `div` for container, two inner `divs` for upper and lower one (orange and gray colored) and, finally, one `table`, positioned absolutely in container `div` how buttons can be equally centered inside container.

```css
.cnt
{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    display:block;
    height:250px;
}
.div1
{
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:orange;
    display:block;
}
.div2
{
   position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:50%;
    background-color:gray;
    display:block;
}
.divC
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;
    background-color:transparent;
}
.divC td {text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;}

.btn
{
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
    border-radius:75px;
    background-color:red;
    display:inline-block;
    border:solid 1px red;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="cnt">
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="divC">
         <tr>
             <td><input type="button" class="btn" value="Button1"></td>
             <td><input type="button" class="btn" value="Button2"></td>
             <td><input type="button" class="btn" value="Button3"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Change `height` of container and `buttons` size (`width` and `height`, and 1/2 of them for `border-radius` to get circled button).

**Update :**

There is **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czkw2yvm/3/)** example using only one `div` (colored by orange and gray, no gradient) and one `table` for `buttons`. Just little changes for same result.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need 2 divs you can apply multiple colors to one div using linear-gradient.

```css
  div{
   height: 160px;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 160px;
   background-image: linear-gradient(orange 50%, gray 50%);
  }
  button{
   border-radius: 80px;
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
   margin-right: 5%;
   border: none;
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 1px black; 
  }
  div button:last-child{
   margin-right: 0;
  }
```

```html
 <div>
  <button>Button 1</button>
  <button>Button 2</button>
  <button>Button 3</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the different background colors shouldn't be placed as different divs, but rather put together as the background of one div. This way, you could use `padding` to put the buttons in the appropriate distance from the top/bottom, and make them overlap the background in the correct place.

example:

```html
    <html>

     <head>
      <style type="text/css">
        .css3gradient {
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: #FFA500;
            filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr=#FFA500, endColorstr=#000000);
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFA500 0%, #000000 100%);
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFA500 0%, #000000 100%);
            background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #FFA500 0%, #000000 100%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(top, #FFA500 0%, #000000 100%);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #FFA500 0%, #000000 100%);
            background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, #FFA500), color-stop(100%, #000000));
         }
        .overlap
        {
          color:White;
          padding-top:40px;
       padding-bottom:30px;
       padding-left:10px;
       padding-right:10px;
        }
     h1
     {
      font-size:180%; /* adding it to demonstrate how you can overlap the middle, this looks well with the current height & width */
     }
      </style>
     </head>

     <body>
      <div class="css3gradient"><b><h1 class="overlap">Here is the result</h1></b>
      </div>
     </body>

    </html>
```